# Highlight element of another page by clicking a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two HTML document, *home.html* and *courses.html*
*home.html* has 4 links each representing(linked) to a part of code(div) on **courses.html**
***What I want:*** When a link is clicked on *home.html* and it is redirected to a specific part of *courses.html* then that part should glow (maybe by box-shadow) to attract reader's attention.
[home.html(rough view)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHmg7.png)

[courses.html(roughly showing effect I want)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omWem.png)

PS: I'm just a beginner and I know only HTML, CSS, Javascript so if this effect is possible using these languages then it will be really great. If not, then pls make me understand that code.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) pseudo class on the intended sections in the 2nd page. Note that the anchor name (the hash after the #) is identical the target element id.

The example works on a single page, but the principle will work on 2 or more pages as well.

```css
div:target {
  border: 2px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<!-- source page -->
<a href="#section1">Go to 1</a>
<a href="#section2">Go to 2</a>
<a href="#section3">Go to 3</a>
<a href="#section4">Go to 4</a>

<!-- target page -->
<div id="section1">Example 1</div>
<div id="section2">Example 2</div>
<div id="section3">Example 3</div>
<div id="section4">Example 4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use the `location.hash`.
When redirecting the user to the `courses.html` page, redirect to an URL with a hash parameter in the URL. for example: `/courses.html#link1`.

Then, ON the `courses.html` page, add this script:

```
$("#"+location.hash).css('box-shadow', '0 5px 5px #08c1c6');
```

I'm using jQuery for better readability. What it does is simple: Adds `box-shadow` to the element which has the ID of the URL hash parameter.
You should add an ID attribute to the divs you want to mark, and then the script will add box-shadow according to the `#` parameter in your URL.

Javascript version for the code:

```
document.getElementById(location.hash).style.boxShadow = "0 5px 5px #08c1c6";
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the link like

**home.html**

```
<a href="courses.html?highlight=something">Go to something</a>
```

*say you want to highlight an element whose id=something

On **courses.html** page run a function on document ready to check for any highlights.

JQUERY:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    CheckForHighlight();
});

function CheckForHighlight(){
    href = window.location.href;
    values = href.split('?')[1] // Remove the url
    highlight = values.split('=')[1]; // Grab the second parmeter
    $('#'+highlight).addClass('highlightedElem');
    //highlightedElemclass has box shadow or border
}
```

CSS:

```
.highlightedElem{
   box-shadow:0px 0px 10px blue;
   border:1px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly, css box shadow for *a:hover* is enough on this

This is css part

```
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px red;
}
```

This is the html part

```
<a href="">for a link 1</a>
```

```css
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px red;
}
```

```html
<a href="">for a link 1</a>
<a href="">for a link 2</a>
<a href="">for a link 3</a>
<a href="">for a link 4</a>
```